# Benefit of promise/future compared to return by reference

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to C++ threads concept and is trying to comprehend the benefit of the promise/future abstraction. With promise and future, I understand that it allows an async function to "return" like a regular subroutine does. However, it is not clear to me what it offers beyond using referenced argument to do the same thing.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void f(int& x)
{
    x += 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    std::thread t(f, std::ref(a));
    t.join();
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

In the above example, I make the function `f()` "returns" the integer by passing a reference. This is safe as I only grab the value after thread is join. Now is there any benefit from using promise/future that the above paradigm cannot do?

Comment: With a "promise" you get a promise that a result will eventually be available at some time in the future. As long as you don't need the result you can let the thread do its work in the background, and whenever you need the result it will hopefully be ready immediately without having to wait for it. Plain threads are more for continuous background work that doesn't need to give a result back.

Comment: If the background thread does something different after the calculation of the new value is complete, you'll want to use future+promise. The same if you don't know about the number of tasks. Also you won't be able to specify a timeout for the wait with the approach posted in the question.

Comment: The sample code is oversimplified. In a more complex example with a thread you have to care of the referenced object lifetime.

Comment: This type of question reminds me of the "goto can do everything 'structured programming' can, and is no less safe or comprehensible as long as you're careful" discussion of the 1960s and 1970s. The lesson that higher-level abstractions are valuable has to be learned over and over again, it seems.

Comment: TLDR: The whole point of a "promise" or a "future" is that it provides a means for a thread to _wait_ until the value is ready to be used. If all you have is a reference to a variable where some other thread eventually will store a value, then how will you know when the store has happened? The future/promise gives you the means to wait for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is safe as I only grab the value after thread is join

Well, that's kind of the point, isn't it? Is it really "safe" if all it takes for some code to become "unsafe" is for someone to inadvertently use the variable at the wrong time? If the difference between "safe" and "completely broken" is changing the order of two lines, and no compiler can catch the problem, is it really "safe?"

If you invoke an asynchronous action, the primary reason you did that was because you wanted to *do something else* while that action is going on. So leaving the current stack frame is kind of the point. Most code does not look like your simplistic example.

Your example is only "safe" *because* it is simplistic. Introduce any complexity, and it becomes increasingly unsafe.

Did the thread raise an exception instead of returning a valid value? Did you make sure that the lifetime of the object being referenced persists until the thread is finished writing to it? If you want the thread to be able to finish with a task and go do a different one (instead of incurring the cost of creating a new `std::thread` every time you want to do an async process), how do you communicate when the value is ready to the outside world?

`promise`/`future` has answers to *all of these* questions. It has an explicit mechanism for sheparding exceptions across threads. The lifetime of the shepherded object is rigidly controlled, so that simply can't break. Each `promise`/`future` is independent and thus a thread could have many of them, and any `future` can tell when the `promise`d value is ready. Etc.

In summary, `promise`/`future` are tools that are safe *at scale*. Yours is increasingly less safe the more complexity is introduced.